# My HP ProBook 4520s running Windows 7 hangs intermittently

Tags: windows-7

I have not been able to trace a consistent cause, but a few times a day my laptop will hang for up to about a minute. I can still move the cursor which displays as the wait icon for whatever application I was last in, but cannot carry out any other actions.

Unfortunately I can't Ctrl+Alt+Del to bring up a task manager and I just have to wait.

I can't pin it down to a particular application either, but generally I have either office apps, a browser or other tools open.

I'm tempted to think it may be network timeout on something, as I can't think of anything else which would delay for that long with such a significant impact, but as I'm more a Unix person I thought it would be worth asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use Reliability Monitor, see if it shows what is hanging the system.

http://www.msigeek.com/5518/measure-hardware-and-software-problems-using-reliability-monitor-in-windows-7

Comment: will try it and pop results back up here as to how well that works. Cheers

Comment: Hmmm - the reliability monitor doesn't show any issues at all on the occasions the machine has hung :-(

Comment: Accepted the answer, as it has finally helped me diagnose the issue by not showing any issues - this helped me narrow it down to network timeouts.